# How to pronounce "Hilary Clinton" like John Gibson?

Tags: pronunciation

I am struggling to pronounce *Hilary Clinton* like Fox News host John Gibson, but it either becomes [hilarI klinhen] or [hilerI klinnen] or [hilerI klinton]. How does he really pronounce it that smoothly?

Comment: It's *Hillary Clinton" if you mean the wife of former president Bill Clinton. Two els (l's).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how John Gibson pronounces it, but dropping/"swallowing" 'd's and 't's is a common way to accelerate one's speech.  Since when they talk on TV about somebody well-known *and* show pictures of them, people are not likely to misunderstand whom exactly they mean by even a [hilri klinn].

Other examples can be "what do you know?" -> "wharraya know?" (d -> r), "lil" instead of "little", etc.